# php expression question

Tags: php

```
function createHash($string) {
    $check1 = $this->stringToNumber($string, 0x1505, 0x21);
    $check2 = $this->stringToNumber($string, 0, 0x1003F);

    $factor = 4;
    $halfFactor = $factor/2;

    $check1 >>= $halfFactor;
    $check1 = (($check1 >> $factor) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($check1 & 0x3F);
    $check1 = (($check1 >> $factor) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($check1 & 0x3FF);
    $check1 = (($check1 >> $factor) & 0x3C000 ) | ($check1 & 0x3FFF);  

    $calc1 = (((($check1 & 0x3C0) << $factor) | 
                ($check1 & 0x3C)) << $halfFactor ) | 
                ($check2 & 0xF0F );
    $calc2 = (((($check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << $factor) |
                ($check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | 
                ($check2 & 0xF0F0000 );

    return ($calc1 | $calc2);
}
```

**>>=** what does this expression stand for? it looks very strange to me. I couldn't find any questions on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the equivalent of `+=` for `>>`.

`>>` is bitwise shift on a binary level.
If an integer/byte has the value `0000 1000` performing `>> 1` on it would make it's new value `0000 0100`, it would slide the bits right inserting zeroes to the left.
`>> 2` would make it `0000 0010` etc.

The effective result would be the same as dividing it by 4 as `>> X` == `/ 2^X`

That code is the same as:

```
$check1 = $check1 >> $halfFactor
```

Answer (score 2):

`>>` means 'Right shift' and the statement you had pointed out - it means

```
$check1 = $check1 >>$halfFactor
```

Answer (score 1):

It is shift right assignment operator.
See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and [this](http://php.comsci.us/etymology/operator/shiftrightassign.php).

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation (bitwise operators)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

This code:

```
$check1 >>= $halfFactor;
```

actually means something like that: divide `$check1` by `2 ^ $halfFactor` times and assign result to `$check1`.